# GTest `--gtest_stream_result_to` how does it work?

Tags: googletest

Looking through the `--help` on any gtest unittest, I see the `--gtest_stream_result_to` option.

Presumably, I can stream my test results, yeah!

But the more I look at it, there is absolutely no documentation on the format of the streaming endpoints or the protocol. I setup the fake server to see what it does, and now I'm making slow progress with seeing things like this: 
`code 400, message Bad request syntax ('gtest_streaming_protocol_version=1.0')`

How do I use this feature? Is the spec for `gtest_streaming_protocol_version` something that is published? Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was put in to facilitate communicating test results to Eclipse. You can reverse engineer the protocol from the [source code](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/c7a03daa99e7c457561b5dd2afc0eddab166e48e/googletest/src/gtest-internal-inl.h#L1130). If you need more info on event listeners in general in order to better understand `StreamingListener`, the documentation has a [section](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#extending-googletest-by-handling-test-events) on it.